# Pandas: using dict (including operators) to return column subset from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

Let's say I got a data frame with columns `a, b, c, d, e` and a dictionary `{"A": "a", "B": "b", "E": "e"}`

a) How do I use this dictionary to return a new data frame (same index) with only those 3 columns (renamed to cap letters)?

b) Alternatively, is there a way to drop any column in the original data frame that is *not* listed in the dictionary and basically reduce the original data frame down to the selection? (with renaming columns?)

Let's further say I had dictionary `{"A": "a", "Diff": "b - c", "Sum": "d + e"}` referencing the columns in my data frame, but also including operators (-, +).

c) Is there a way to return a new data frame (same index) with 3 new columns with data from my original data frame "aggregated" as described by the operators?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `eval`-- not the Python function of the same name, but the [DataFrame method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval).

```
In [50]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape((3,5)), columns=list("abcde"))

In [51]: df
Out[51]: 
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14

In [52]: d = {"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c"}

In [53]: d2 = {"A": "a", "Diff": "b - c", "Sum": "d + e"}
```

Using the DataFrame constructor instead of `pd.concat` on individual series:

```
In [87]: pd.DataFrame({k: df.eval(v) for k,v in d.items()})
Out[87]: 
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   5   6   7
2  10  11  12

In [88]: pd.DataFrame({k: df.eval(v) for k,v in d2.items()})
Out[88]: 
    A  Diff  Sum
0   0    -1    7
1   5    -1   17
2  10    -1   27
```

Comment: I guess we can do it without using `pd.concat()`: `df.eval('\n'.join(['{} = {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d2.items()]), inplace=False)`

Comment: @MaxU: I think I prefer just passing a dict to DataFrame.  I thought I tried that originally and something went wrong with the Series names but I must have done something wrong because it seems to be working now (?)..

Comment: AFAIK using `df.eval()` allows us to add multiple columns only if a new column is on a new line, hence `'\n'.join(...)`

Comment: I admire your determination, I gave up at the "can only assign a single expression" error and didn't go any further. ;-)

Comment: I was thinking about iterating over d/d2 and appending one column at a time, with or without the math. This is similar, but much slicker (and more pythonic lol). Hadn't used the eval function in a while, but this is a nice way of using it. THANKS!

Comment: Can I do the same if I have a second data frame instead of a dictionary? I guess I'm looking for the `k: df.eval(v) for k,v in d.items()` equivalent for a data frame .... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I used a [DF, generated by @DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735343/5741205):

```
In [145]: d2 = {"A": "a", "Diff": "b - c", "Sum": "d + e"}

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
```

Multi-line queries allow us to add multiple columns using `DataFrame.eval()`:

```
In [147]: df.eval('\n'.join(['{} = {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d2.items()]), inplace=False)
Out[147]:
    a   b   c   d   e   A  Diff  Sum
0   0   1   2   3   4   0    -1    7
1   5   6   7   8   9   5    -1   17
2  10  11  12  13  14  10    -1   27
```

NOTE: it'll work only in the case when new columns appear on a new line

Explanation:

```
In [148]: print('\n'.join(['{} = {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d2.items()]))
A = a
Diff = b - c
Sum = d + e
```

You can even use new columns in further calculations (pay attention at `"new"` column):

```
In [152]: d3 = {"Diff": "b - c", "Sum": "d + e", "new": "Sum - Diff"}

In [153]: df.eval('\n'.join(['{} = {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d3.items()]), inplace=False)
Out[153]:
    a   b   c   d   e  Diff  Sum  new
0   0   1   2   3   4    -1    7    8
1   5   6   7   8   9    -1   17   18
2  10  11  12  13  14    -1   27   28
```

Comment: Wow ... this is impressive! Took me a moment to wrap my head around ... in my case, however, I try to reduce to a new data frame, drop the original one, and only work with the data I actually need ... which makes me wonder: maybe I could just instruct the read_csv function to only read the data/columns I need ... but that's for another day ... :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding questions a and b, the following will work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 5), columns=list('abcde'))

          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.653701 -1.267756  0.680395  0.997065  1.389126
1 -1.598463  2.595352  0.983189 -0.130996  0.605120
2  0.631091 -1.293486  0.095808 -0.474806 -0.353356
3  1.867020  2.164540  0.021103  1.810129  1.114983

d = {"A": "a", "B": "b", "E": "e"}
```

Then, for Python 2,

```
df[d.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in d.items()})
```

and, for Python 3.x (see MaxU's comment)

```
df.loc[:, d.values()].rename(columns={v: k for k, v in d.items()})
```

give you the desired output:

```
          A         B         E
0  0.653701 -1.267756  1.389126
1 -1.598463  2.595352  0.605120
2  0.631091 -1.293486 -0.353356
3  1.867020  2.164540  1.114983
```

Comment: And I suppose you could use `df.query` for the third question

Comment: Please be aware that this solution doesn't work under Python 3.x. Use: `df.loc[:, d.values()].rename(columns={v:k for k,v in d.items()})` instead

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks, I edited my post accordingly (and also upvoted yours, nice solution).

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking at `eval` but MaxU and DSM were far faster (as always ;) ).